# Mysterious empty page + subsequent "Overfull \vbox has occurred while \output is active" during a long string of sectioning commands

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, warnings, sections-paragraphs

Document in question: http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/nJhaYvfN

Page 3 is typeset as a blank page, while page 4 has the overfull (by almost 160pts!) `\vbox` during a long string of sectioning commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX has troubles breaking pages that are entirely made up of sectioning commands; insert some filler text into these sections.

Comment: This seems to be it.

Comment: Because the accept function confused me.  It's accepted now.